# UnsatisfiedLinkError and JNLP4-connect problem from docker.push in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, x86-64, amd-processor, ppc64le

While trying to run a `docker.push` on a ppc64le Jenkins slave called by an x86 Jenkins master, the following error occurs.

```
Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from <IP1>/<IP2>

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll3535546627560640699.so: /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll3535546627560640699.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can’t load AMD 64-bit .so on a Power PC 64-bit platform
```

Whole log

```
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from IP1/IP2:PORT
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.docker.utils.DockerAgentUtils.getImageIdFromAgent(DockerAgentUtils.java:303)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.DockerPushStep$Execution.run(DockerPushStep.java:122)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.DockerPushStep$Execution.run(DockerPushStep.java:86)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll3535546627560640699.so: /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll3535546627560640699.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load AMD 64-bit .so on a Power PC 64-bit platform)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:214)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:269)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.IovArray.<clinit>(IovArray.java:57)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.<init>(EpollEventLoop.java:62)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:130)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:35)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:58)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.<init>(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:100)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.<init>(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:87)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.<init>(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:64)
    at com.github.dockerjava.netty.NettyDockerCmdExecFactory$UnixDomainSocketInitializer.init(NettyDockerCmdExecFactory.java:220)
    at com.github.dockerjava.netty.NettyDockerCmdExecFactory.init(NettyDockerCmdExecFactory.java:196)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.withDockerCmdExecFactory(DockerClientImpl.java:161)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuilder.java:45)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.docker.utils.DockerUtils.getDockerClient(DockerUtils.java:326)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.docker.utils.DockerUtils.getImageIdFromTag(DockerUtils.java:37)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.docker.utils.DockerAgentUtils$6.call(DockerAgentUtils.java:305)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.docker.utils.DockerAgentUtils$6.call(DockerAgentUtils.java:303)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from IP1/IP2:PORT failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:961)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.docker.utils.DockerAgentUtils.getImageIdFromAgent(DockerAgentUtils.java:303)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.DockerPushStep$Execution.run(DockerPushStep.java:122)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.DockerPushStep$Execution.run(DockerPushStep.java:86)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is not to use the syntax provided in Jenkins and just wrap docker commands inside `sh`.

```
sh """
docker build . -t ${imageTag}
docker push ${imageTag}
"""
```